# rails AJAX js.erb same route more actions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have rails4 app with bootstrap tabs. I have the root `/common_medias` for all the tabs, and loading the data w/ AJAX + `format.js` + js.erb for each tab when user clicks on the given tab. My problem is that I also wanna do infinite scrolling w/ the help of will_pagination gem, but the js.erb file is already used for loading the initial data. At the moment both the bootstarp tab js action and will_pagination js action point to the same url, so both try to use the same js.erb which causes some problems.

What is the good workaround? Creating a new controller action so there will be separated js.erb files (This one seems to be weird since pagination and original data will be separated). Or should I use conditionals in the single js.erb file to check what was the trigger action (loading data on tab click/ scrolling). I don't know how to implement any of these, so pls provide some code based on mine with the preferred way.

common_medias.html.erb

```
  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#filestab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= common_medias_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="file">Files</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#linkstab" aria-controls="linkstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= common_medias_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="link">Links</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#calendarstab" aria-controls="calendarstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= common_medias_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="filestab">
        <%= render partial: "common_medias/message_file" %>
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="linkstab">
        #LOADED BY JS ON TABCLICK    
      </div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="calendarstab">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

common_medias controller

```
 def common_medias
    @param_id = request.parameters['user_id']
    @user = User.find(@param_id)
    @conversation ||= Conversation.between(current_user.id, @user.id).first
    @common_files = @conversation.messages.with_file.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:files], per_page: 3)
    if params[:tab] == "file"
      @common_files = @conversation.messages.with_file.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:files], per_page: 3)
    end
    #messages can have multiple links, but with the following each link can be displayed separately with files
    if params[:tab] == "link"
      @message_links_pre = @conversation.messages.with_link.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:links], per_page: 3)
      @message_links = @message_links_pre.map { |f| { link: f.link, created_at: f.created_at, user_id: f.user_id} }.flatten
      @common_links = formatting_links(@message_links)
    end
    if params[:tab] == "calendar"
      #implementing later
    end 
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

common_medias.js

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {

//infinite scrolling for tasks based on pagination gem
    if ($('#infinite-common-file-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      $('#infinite-common-file-scrolling').hide();
      var more_common_files_url;
      more_common_files_url = $('#infinite-common-file-scrolling .pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      if (more_common_files_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />');
        $('#infinite-common-file-scrolling').show();
        $.getScript(more_common_files_url);
      }
    });
  };

  if ($('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').size() > 0) {
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').hide();
      var more_common_links_url;
      more_common_links_url = $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination .next_page a').attr('href');
      if (more_common_links_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
        $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />');
        $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').show();
        $.getScript(more_common_links_url);
      }
    });
  };
});

$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
  var target = $(this).data("activetab");
  var href = $(this).data("link");
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: href,
    data: {tab: target},
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
```

common_medias.js.erb

```
//tabclick code
<% if params[:tab] == "file" %>
    var filebody = $('.tab-pane.active');
    filebody.html('<%= j render partial: "common_medias/message_file" %>');
<% elsif params[:tab] == "link" %>
    var linkbody= $('.tab-pane.active');
    linkbody.html('<%= j render partial: "common_medias/message_link" %>');
<% end %>

//CODE SHOULD RECOGNIZE WHICH ONE TO INVOKE  
//pagination code for files
$('.tab-pane.active').append;
<% if @common_files.next_page %>
  $('#infinite-common-file-scrolling .pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @common_files %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('#infinite-common-file-scrolling .pagination').remove();
  $('.no-more').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
<% end %>

//pagination code for links
$('.tab-pane.active').append;
<% if @message_links_pre.next_page %>
  $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @message_links_pre %>');
<% else %>
  $(window).off('scroll');
  $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination').remove();
  $('.no-more').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
<% end %>
```

UPDATE

Changing tabs work well (goes to /get_links, fetching the data and renders get_links.js.erb). Will_paginate gem shows the proper URL in the DOM(/get_links), yet on scrolling common_media.js.erb will be rendered instead of get_links.js.erb.

common_medias controller

```
def common_medias
    @messages = @conversation.messages.includes(:user).order(created_at: :desc).limit(50).reverse
    @message = Message.new
    @common_files = @conversation.messages.with_file.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:files], per_page: 3)
    # respond_to do |format| COMMENTED OUT STILL PAGINATION GOES FOR common_medias.js.erb
    #   format.html
    #   format.js
    # end
  end

def get_links
  @message_links_pre = @conversation.messages.with_link.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:links], per_page: 3)
  @message_links = @message_links_pre.map { |f| { link: f.link, created_at: f.created_at, user_id: f.user_id} }.flatten
  @common_links = formatting_links(@message_links)
  respond_to :js
end
```

common_medias.html.erb

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#filestab" aria-controls="filestab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_files_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="file">Files</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#linkstab" aria-controls="linkstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= get_links_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="link">Links</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#calendarstab" aria-controls="calendarstab" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" data-link = "<%= common_medias_user_common_medias_path(@user)%>" data-activetab="calendar">Calendar</a></li>
    </ul>
```

common_media.js

```
if ($('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').size() > 0) {
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').hide();
    var more_common_links_url;
    more_common_links_url = $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination .next_page a').attr('href'); //SHOWS /get_links?will_paginate_params url here
    if (more_common_links_url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 60) {
      $('.pagination').html('<img src="/assets/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." title="Loading..." />');
      $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
              url: more_common_links_url,
              data: {scrolling: "linkscroll"},
              dataType: "script"
            });
     }
  });
};
```

common_medias.js.erb

```
alert('whyyou');
```

get_links.js.erb

```
alert('hahalinks');
<% if params[:scrolling] == "linkscroll" %>
    $('.linkbody').append('<%= j render partial: "common_medias/message_link" %>');
    <% if @message_links_pre.next_page %>
    $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate @message_links_pre %>');
  <% else %>
    $(window).off('scroll');
    $('#infinite-common-link-scrolling .pagination').remove();
    $('.no-more').delay(1000).fadeIn(1500);
  <% end %>
<% else %>
    var linkbody= $('.tab-pane.active');
    linkbody.html('<%= j render partial: "common_medias/message_link" %>');
<% end %>
```

### [image: first_image]

[image: second_image]

Comment: Your code is all messed up. You should have separate actions for different tabs. At the end of page, for a particular tab you should basically request for 2nd page data and then simply append that data. Think of it as a normal pagination.

Comment: Mandeep I know it is messed up :(. Here is my main problem: Let's say I make different action for all the tab clicks, then when I click on one tab the data will be loaded w/ js and the will_pagination site urls will appear in the DOM. I tried to change the the will_paginate urls to tie them to another action, but it didn't work, so currently the same action name belongs both to the tab click&scrolling and try to decide what to do based on the trigger event. What would you do? Same action different format.js file render/ same js.erb with conditionals/ different action somehow for tab&scroll?

Comment: I still didn't understand, what is the problem in using separate actions for tabs?

Comment: Mandeep, updated my question (everything below UPDATE)

Comment: `yet on scrolling common_media.js.erb will be rendered instead of get_links.js.erb.`, Why is it going there? Try to debug it and in HTML where is 'infinite-common-link-scrolling' id, I don't see it in your code

Comment: Attached two images. As u see in the first the DOM shows get_links and if I hover the mouse over it shows the same. On the top of this common_medias action is set not to response to js. Totally weird.

Comment: Mandeep, it's a pagination gem problem, I could make it work with the files tab. For link tab as I have to change to structure of the active_record_relation response the pagination somehow gets screwed up. It's because I save one attribute (links) as an array to the db and when I fetch the data from db I put it into different rows. As I see pagination gem doesn't like it.